# Builtin camera is unable to capture frame using cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV. How do I capture an image frame from a builtin webcam using `cv2.VideoCapture()`?

```
import cv2, time
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

video.release()
check,frame = video.read()
print(check)
print(frame)
time.sleep(3)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This produces the following output:

```
False
None
```

Why does it return `False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [docs for `VideoCapture::release`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-release). According to them it

> Closes video file or capturing device.

That's not what you want. Remove the `video.release()`. Then `VideoCapture::read()` should succeed.

Starting out with OpenCV it's often easiest to start from some tutorial code and then modify as needed. For example, [this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) is the first thing that comes up for a search for "OpenCV VideoCapture tutorial":

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```